# Beginner UFW question about destination any

Tags: firewalls

I'm learning about UFW with a Raspberry Pi and I don't a couple of things when it comes to UFW rules. Can anyone help me suss a couple things out?

1. My first question is about the destination `any`. If I want to let something connect to my Pi, why use `any` instead of a static IP address?

   Is it in case the Pi's IP address changes? For example:

   ```
   sudo ufw allow from 15.15.15.51 to any port 22
   ```
2. My second question is about the following rule, which I just can't understand. When I wanted to let everything on my network access my Pi I added the rule to the Pi's UFW and it worked, but I have no idea what it means or how to read it.

   It sounds like I'm letting everything on my local network connect to my Pi, regardless of its IP address:

   ```
   sudo ufw allow in to 192.168.1.0/24
   ```

   How does that work?

Comment: In reguards to your first question, you specify *any* because a device can have multiple network interfaces and thus multiple IP addresses.

Comment: The second rule has somewhat strange syntax IMO. I would have written it "sudo ufw allow from 192.168.1.0/24 to any"